# Alternative formulations of Euler's summation formula

Tags: number-theory, summation

Euler's summation formula goes like this:

$$
\sum_{y < n \le x} f(n)
= \int_y^x f(t)\,dt + \int_y^x (t - [t])f'(t)\,dt - f(x)(x - [x]) + f(y)(y - [y])
$$

I will now distribute the multiplications over subtractions and rearrange the terms to get this:

$$
\sum_{y < n \le x} f(n)
= f(x)[x] - f(y)[y] - \int_y^x [t]f'(t)\,dt + \int_y^x tf'(t)\,dt + \int_y^x f(t)\,dt - xf(x) + yf(y)
$$

I will now use the following short-hands for the first three terms and the last four terms, respectively:

\begin{align*}
F(x, y) &= f(x)[x] - f(y)[y] - \int_y^x [t]f'(t)\,dt \\
G(x, y) &= \int_y^x tf'(t)\,dt + \int_y^x f(t)\,dt - xf(x) + yf(y)
\end{align*}

Now $ G(x, y) = 0 $. This can be seen easily with integration by parts:

\begin{align*}
\int_y^x tf'(t)\,dt = xf(x) - yf(y) - \int_y^xf(t)\,dt
\end{align*}

If we now bring all the terms to the LHS, we get $ G(x, y) = 0 $.

My questions:

- Euler's summation formula is written as $ \sum_{y < n \le x} f(n) = F(x, y) + G(x, y) $. Why are the $ G(x, y) $ terms kept when they equal zero? Why isn't Euler's summation formula written as $ \sum_{y < n \le x} f(n) = F(x, y) $ only?
- What about $ \sum_{y < n \le x} f(n) = F(x, y) - G(x, y)$? Is this valid too? Is it useful in analytic number theory?

Comment: The point of Euler's formula is to write the sum as $\int_{y}^{x} f(t)\,dt$ (which hopefully can be explicitly evaluated without too much fuss) plus an error term that has smaller order. For that, it is counterproductive to split up the $u - \lfloor u\rfloor$ terms.